# Implementing Emojis in a VueJs App

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, emoji, emojione, twemoji

I am looking to setup emojis to my chat-app project.
I really liked the emojis in slack / tweeter and I would like to have something similar.

I found the following libraries: (if anyone can suggest a better library I would love to hear)

[emojionearea](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea)

[wdt-emoji-bundle](https://ned.im/wdt-emoji-bundle/#docs)

I am not sure how to load these libraries and use them in a VueJS app.
Could anyone please assist with how to load and use them?

I would like to mention I tried to use [emoji-mart-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-mart-vue)
but not sure how to add the the  component to the template at run time.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tldr;** Checkout demo and code on [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/riyaz_ali/5Lhex13n)

---

This answer is divided into two parts. First part deals with how to `import` all the stuff into the environment while the second part deals with how to use it Vue.

This solution uses [**EmojiOne**](https://github.com/emojione/emojione) as the emoji provider and [**EmojioneArea**](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea) to provide *emoji autocomplete* behavior.

---

### Part 1: Adding the libraries

There are **three ways** in which you can do this.

- Using Global `<script>` tag (not recommended for anything serious): You can add the `<script>` tags for all the dependencies in order and simply start using the Global objects.
  Add these `<script>` in order:

  1. `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`
  2. `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js`
  3. `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emojione@3.1.6/lib/js/emojione.min.js`
  4. `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.textcomplete/1.8.4/jquery.textcomplete.min.js`
  5. `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojionearea/3.4.1/emojionearea.min.js`
- Using AMD modules (using [`require.js`](http://requirejs.org)): You can use the following configuration to load these modules *asynchronously* using `require.js`

  ```
  require.config({
    paths: {
      'jquery': 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1',
      'Vue': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue',
      'emojione': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emojione@3.1.6/lib/js/emojione',
      'jquery.textcomplete': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.textcomplete/1.8.4/jquery.textcomplete',
      'emojionearea': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojionearea/3.4.1/emojionearea'
    },
    shim: {
      'emojione': {
        'exports': 'emojione'
      }
    }
  })
  ```

  You can then require these modules in your entry point as

  ```
  require(['jquery', 'Vue', 'emojione'], function($, Vue, emojione){ /* ... */ })
  ```
- Using `webpack`: All the above libraries are available via `npm` and you install and use them just as you would do with any other library. No special config required.

**BONUS:** Using `webpack` with `require.js` and offloading network and caching loads to CDN!
I often use this setup for my projects and this improves reliability and performance of your site. You can use [`webpack.externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) to instruct `webpack` to not bundle any vendor dependencies and instead you provide them yourself, either by manually adding `<script>` tags or using `require.js`.

Start by adding this to your `webpack.<whatever>.js`

```
//...
output: {
  libraryTarget: 'umd'   // export app as a library
},
//...
externals: {
  'jquery': 'jquery',
  'vue': 'Vue',
  'emojione': 'emojione'
},
//...
```

Then, in your `require.js` entry, add this

```
//...
map: {
  // any module requesting jquery should get shield
  "*": {
    "jquery": "jquery-shield"
  },
  // shield should get original jquery
  "jquery-shield": {
    "jquery": "jquery"
  },
  // patch plugins
  "jquery.textcomplete": {
    "jquery": "jquery"
  },
  "emojionearea": {
    "jquery": "jquery"
  }
}
//...
// define shield, require all the plugins here
define('jquery-shield', ['jquery', 'jquery-textcomplete', 'emojionearea'], function($){ return $ })
```

and then add `require(...)` your webpack bundle

---

### Part 2: Using EmojiOne with Vue

As the OP mentioned his/her case is to use emojis in a chat app, I would also explain the solution with that case, though this can (and should) be modified for other use cases too!

The solution focuses on two aspects. First is to *simply* display the emoji in a `message` component, i.e., no need to display an *emoji picker* dialog and second is to display a emoji picker dialog whilst the user is typing into (say) a textarea.

To achieve the first goal, you can use a message component like,

```
Vue.component('message', {
  props: ['content'],
  render: function(h){
    return h('div', {
      class: { 'message': true }
    }, [
      h('div', {
        class: { 'bubble': true },
        domProps: {
          innerHTML: emojione.toImage(this.content)
        }
      })
    ])
  }
})
```

This would create a `<message />` component which you can use as

```
<message content="Hey :hugging:!!" />
```

which will render

```
<div class="message">
  <div class="bubble">
    Hey <img class="emojione" alt="" title=":hugging:" src="...">!!
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, to create a `<message-box />` component that will display an emoji picker to assist in `autocomplete`, do as follows

```
Vue.component('message-box', {
  template: `<div class="message-box"><textarea></textarea></div>`,
  mounted(){
    // find the input
    $(this.$el).find('textarea').emojioneArea()
  }
})
```

And that's it! Although it may seem like a lot, the crux of the solution is quiet simple! Just use `emojione.toImage(str)` to get a `DOM string` and apply it to the Vue component (you can also use `v-html` to do this but IMO `render()` is a bit more sleek!). And for the displaying the picker, you just call `$(...).emojioneArea()` on the `<textarea />` once the component is mounted.

Make sure to checkout full code example at https://jsfiddle.net/riyaz_ali/5Lhex13n

Comment: I appreciate your help.
It's so nice to have people like you around :)

After reading your answer I believe I need to spend more time reading about webpack and vueJs.

Is it possible to send you direct messages and collaborate with you in case I need any help?

Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Glad to help @sfdcdev ... sure you can always look up for your doubts here on StackOverflow and always ask new questions whenever you get stuck!! I am always around and am sure either me or someone else from this lovely community would definitely help you find your way around :) You can also reach me on the networks mentioned in my profile! Have a good day!!